# Python Selenium not clicking button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Why would selenium not find the element using `xpath`?

```
<input class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="loginButton" accesskey="l" value="Login" tabindex="6" type="submit">
```

Using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-success']").click()
```

I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@class='btn btn-success']
```

Tried css selector as well

Comment: Either you might be trying to click it before it loads, or it may be in an iframe. Have you tried with explicit wait for the element?

Comment: @supputuri you are right, I did time.sleep(5) and it clicked.. Good catch

Comment: I would prefer explicit wait as mentioned in my below answer rather hard coded, `time.sleep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with explicit wait.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.btn.btn-success")).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this one worked for me best, `WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='btn btn-success']"))).click()`

Answer (score 0):

Try another attribute

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='loginButton']").click()
```